# How can I make my page sliding up and down?

Tags: android, button, layout, sliding

I want to make 47 button on a layout and I can't figure it out how to make space for all of them on my layout, and making the layout sliding up and down.. I know, there is a lot of subjects about this, but I tried all of them, I nothing helped me.. So, please, if somebody can explain and write a layout full of buttons and all the files required in the sliding process. Please, and thank you very much, I'll be greaful. Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure you want that many buttons?  It would likely violate many UI/UX standards.

Comment: what exactly have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

try this it will help you.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            />
        .
        .
        .
    </LinearLayout>  
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know, there is a lot of subjects about this, but I tried all of
>   them, I nothing helped me

did you read about scrollview

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html